# WebProvisioned Event Is Not Firing When Creating SPWebs Programmatically

Tags: event-receivers, spweb

I have a WebProvisioned event receiver and i do some work in this event receiver. When i create new webs from a console application programmatically, it seems the event receiver does not fire? Is this an expected situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of a question on MSDN:
[webprovisioned event not firing when subwebs are created programatically or with powershell](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/815217d6-bc9d-47ff-909b-0b8d8a459c53)

Answers from above:

> 2 things need to consider here
>
> 1. Proper rights of user who runs the power shell command.
> 2. Event receiver should not have SPContext object in it. As its null in case of powershell while its available while you directly working
>      through site.

Other notable thing:

> Have you tested if the receiver gets triggered but fails to execute?
>   (put a System.Debugger.Break(); at the first line.

Irrelevant to the question, but just to keep the information at one place:

> **Notes to implementers** 
>   Since an event receiver has to be registered
>   with the site collection before it's handlers can execute, the
>   WebAdding and WebProvisioned handlers cannot run when a site
>   collection and its root web site are created.
>   Ref: [SPWebEventReceiver.WebProvisioned method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver.webprovisioned.aspx)